# Is there API in QuickBooks online to retrieve fields of a particular Object?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

How to retrieve fields/attributes of a particular Object (Account,Customer.etc) in QuickBooks Online using API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to retrieve fields/attributes of a particular Object (Account,Customer.etc) in QuickBooks Online using API ?

You can't.

The QuickBooks Online API does not support this.

Use the documentation to determine what fields are supported:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting